# Figure out the problematic index in ES cluster?

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, monitoring, datadog

I have  elastic-search cluster which hosts more than 15 indices, I have a Datadog integration which shows me the below view of my elastic-search cluster.

We have alert integration with DD(datadog) which gives us alert if overall CPU usage goes beyond 60% and also in our application we start getting alerts when **elasticsearch cluster is under stress** as in this case our response time increases beyond a configures threshold.

Now my problem is how to know which indices are consuming the ES cluster resources most, so that we can fine either throttle the request from those indices or optimize their requests.

Some things which we did:

1. Looked at the slow query log: Which doesn't give us the culprit as due to heavy load or CPU usage, we have slow queries log from almost all the big indices.
2. Like in the DD dashboard there is spike in the `bulk` queue, but this is overall and not specific to a particular ES indices.

So my problem is very simple and all I want some metric from DD or elastic which can easily tell me which indices are consuming the most resources on a elastic-search cluster.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortuanetly I can not propose an exact solution/workaround to you but you might have a look at the following documentations/API's:

[Indices Stats API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-stats.html)

[Cluster Stats API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-stats.html)

[Nodes Stats API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-nodes-stats.html)

The cpu usage is not included in the exported fields but maybe you can derive a high cpu usage behaviour from the other fields.

I hope I could help you in some way.

Comment: Sure, although I am aware of these api and used cluster and nodes api, let me look at indices api and get back to you. although it would be better if I don't have to hit these api and manually parse their O/P, instead of this some monitoring tool or ES api, which itself can give the indices using the highest number of resources or getting the highest load is given in API

Comment: Can't you change the scope to focus only on a single index?

Comment: @Val, not I can't and even lets suppose If its possible, wont it be too much to go each and every index and see whats happening with them, rather than I would like to have a leader-board, where top indices based on their search and index request are listed.

Comment: I'd say change to Kibana monitoring, which provides exactly that ;-)

Comment: @Val I looked through the .monitoring-es indices but couldnt find a cpu usage per index. Could you explain where one can find that info?

Comment: CPU usage can only be per host/node, not per index. Index metrics can be indexing/searching latency/throughput, refresh time, segment count, etc

Comment: @Val, we are already using Datadog(DD), hence it would be difficult to introduce another monitoring tool(Kibana in this case), also we have more than 20 cluster to monitor(would it mean 20 different kibana or just one kibana can do the magic ??)

Comment: Kibana can monitor any number of clusters. I don't know DD very well, but I'm really not sure that index-level monitoring is available there. You'd have to get the index stats of all your indices and check which ones are causing problems...

Comment: @Val, I checked and looks like kibana monitoring can solve the issue, but looks like for that atleast we need to buy elastic gold plan as mentioned in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-overview/7.3/monitoring-production.html